# Using mean versus qui mean in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a following code with the output:

```
sysuse auto,clear
clear matrix

local vars price weight length
foreach i of local vars{
qui mean `i'
mat `i'=r(table)
scalar mean_`i'=`i'[1,1]
scalar se_`i'=`i'[2,1]
scalar n_`i'=`i'[7,1]+1
scalar sd_`i'=se_`i'*sqrt(n_`i')
mat des_`i'=(n_`i',mean_`i',sd_`i')
mat colnames  des_`i'=Observations Mean SD
mat rownames des_`i'=`i'
mat des_result=nullmat(des_result)\des_`i'
}

estout matrix(des_result,fmt(0 4 4))


---------------------------------------------------
               des_result                          
             Observations         Mean           SD
---------------------------------------------------
price                   .            .            .
weight                  .            .            .
length                  .            .            .
---------------------------------------------------
```

Now if I only change  `` qui mean `i' `` to `` mean `i' ``, I have an output:

```
 sysuse auto,clear
    clear matrix

local vars price weight length
foreach i of local vars{
mean `i'
mat `i'=r(table)
scalar mean_`i'=`i'[1,1]
scalar se_`i'=`i'[2,1]
scalar n_`i'=`i'[7,1]+1
scalar sd_`i'=se_`i'*sqrt(n_`i')
mat des_`i'=(n_`i',mean_`i',sd_`i')
mat colnames  des_`i'=Observations Mean SD
mat rownames des_`i'=`i'
mat des_result=nullmat(des_result)\des_`i'
}

estout matrix(des_result,fmt(0 4 4))


---------------------------------------------------
               des_result                          
             Observations         Mean           SD
---------------------------------------------------
price                  74    6165.2568    2949.4959
weight                 74    3019.4595     777.1936
length                 74     187.9324      22.2663
---------------------------------------------------
```

I was wondering why I am not getting the output when I use `qui`. Note this has nothing to do with `estout`.  It has to do with `mean`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I get output with both pieces of code (Stata 12.1 for Unix).

Comment: I also can't reproduce this,... additionally on the second example there is additionally output after the close of the loop before estout call, which you don't seem to have displayed

Comment: @D3L, the additional output is due to the lack of `qui`, but that is expected.

Comment: @Roberto, yep, just strange why he doesn't have it in his display...

Comment: @  Roberto: I am using Stata 12 for Windows. @  D3L: That was typo while pasting the code. I corrected that. Thanks.

Comment: Update `estout` to see if this is a fixed bug. Also, since the first block of code does produce the desired matrix, at least for me in Stata 13.1, I don't think you have ruled out a problem with `estout`.

Comment: @ Nick: Thanks, but I didn't get the desired matrix with `qui mean` ;so ,I ruled out a problem with the `estout`.

Comment: See below for what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use `estout` (SSC/SJ) but this shows (as others have reported) my complete failure to reproduce the reported problem that the matrix of desired results is empty when `quietly` is applied:

```
. about 

Stata/SE 13.1 for Windows (64-bit x86-64)
Revision 03 Jul 2014
Copyright 1985-2013 StataCorp LP
```

local and personal details edited out

```
. sysuse auto,clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. clear matrix

. local vars price weight length
. foreach i of local vars{
2. qui mean `i'
3. mat `i'=r(table)
4. scalar mean_`i'=`i'[1,1]
5. scalar se_`i'=`i'[2,1]
6. scalar n_`i'=`i'[7,1]+1
7. scalar sd_`i'=se_`i'*sqrt(n_`i')
8. mat des_`i'=(n_`i',mean_`i',sd_`i')
9. mat colnames  des_`i'=Observations Mean SD
10. mat rownames des_`i'=`i'
11. mat des_result=nullmat(des_result)\des_`i'
12. }


. mat li des_result 

 des_result[3,3]
        Observations          Mean            SD
 price            74     6165.2568     2949.4959
 weight           74     3019.4595     777.19357
 length           74     187.93243      22.26634
```

Comment: Thanks again. It's weird that I can't get the output when I use the `qui`.